# Rollup with gulp and typescript outputs Cannot find module 'tslib/tslib.es6.js'

Tags: rollupjs

I followed the typescript gulp in the doc :https://rollupjs.org/guide/en#gulp

here is my gulp file :

```
const gulp = require("gulp");
const rollup = require("rollup");
const rollupTypescript = require("rollup-plugin-typescript");

gulp.task("build", () => {
  return rollup
    .rollup({
      input: "./main.ts",
      plugins: [rollupTypescript()]
    })
    .then(bundle => {
      return bundle.write({
        file: "./main.js",
        format: "umd",
        name: "library",
        sourcemap: true
      });
    });
});
```

```
Error: Cannot find module 'tslib/tslib.es6.js' from 'C:\projets\Tests\rollup\node_modules\rollup-plugin-typescript\dist'
    at Function.module.exports [as sync] (C:\projets\Tests\rollup\node_modules\resolve\lib\sync.js:58:15)
    at typescript (C:\projets\Tests\rollup\node_modules\rollup-plugin-typescript\dist\rollup-plugin-typescript.cjs.js:109:29)
    at gulp.task (C:\projets\Tests\rollup\gulpfile.js:9:17)
    at taskWrapper (C:\projets\Tests\rollup\node_modules\undertaker\lib\set-task.js:13:15)
    at bound (domain.js:301:14)
    at runBound (domain.js:314:12)
    at asyncRunner (C:\projets\Tests\rollup\node_modules\async-done\index.js:55:18)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

Anyone knows why this is happening is this a bug with rollup or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You need [tslib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tslib), which is a [peer dependency](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-typescript#installation) of `rollup-plugin-typescript`.

```
npm i -D tslib
```